# jQuery Animate won't move for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

At wit's end here. Sorry if this is a similar question to the other 20 I've looked at, but I've tried everything and can't figure out why mine won't work.

```
    <style>
      .block {
      position:relative;
      background-color:#abc;
      left:50px;
      width:500px;
      height:90px;
      margin:5px;
      overflow:hidden;
       }
     </style>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(".wth").click(function(){
        $(".block").animate({left: "500px"}, 1500);
        });
   </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
 <button class="wth">Move it!</button>
 <div class="block" style="border:#333 3px solid;">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate egestas consectetur. Donec ornare, orci in dapibus euismod, libero ante viverra ante, a pretium felis odio quis eros.
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
```

Just trying to learn to use the `.animate()` method with jQuery, so not looking to use a plugin here. I was inspired to learn this from the [about us](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oriqom/1/edit)**</kbd>

You need a DOM ready that listen for the DOM is ready to be manipulated, which means your elements are now inside a collection, ready to be accessed.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$(function(){ // DOCUMENT ready shorthand

    $(".wth").click(function(){
        $(".block").animate({left: 500}, 1500);
     });

});
```

Comment: And if this answer doesn't make sense as is, you're not attaching the listener to anything. Using this $(function(){}); method, you are binding the listener, likewise with document ready, but it is common thought that this way is better. FYI, this is for OP. obviously roXon knows this

Comment: SMH. I added the shorthand and it worked. I tried adding the full `$(document).ready()` bit before posting the question and removed when it didn't work. Thanks roXon!

Comment: @ckpepper02 you're welcome! Hope we managed to explain the issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    <style>
      .block {
      position:relative;
      background-color:#abc;
      left:50px;
      width:500px;
      height:90px;
      margin:5px;
      overflow:hidden;
       }
     </style>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(this).on('click', 'button.wth', function(){
            $('.block').animate({
                left: '250px',
            });
        });
    });
   </script>
```

....

```
<div class="block" style="border:#333 3px solid;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate egestas consectetur. Donec ornare, orci in dapibus euismod, libero ante viverra ante, a pretium felis odio quis eros.
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div></body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Connor. I tried that earlier but I must have typed something wrong. SMH.